# Logic to use multiple webview in TabLayout to handle memory issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have almost 30 webview in a Tablayout. Everything works fine but my app consumes a lot of memory and will just close because of memory issue. This is what I get in log

```
04-05 21:00:09.458 19720-19801/com.example.choman.webview A/chromium: [FATAL:memory.cc(19)] Out of memory. size=16777216
```

This is my java file. Basically all the remaining 29 fragments contain the same code with just a change in the url. I am not sure how to handle this.

```
public class stackOverflow extends Fragment {


    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout1;




    public stackOverflow() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);


    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.website_detail_1);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);


        mSwipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe1);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            }
        });

        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout1.isRefreshing()) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
        }


        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("pageFinished", "yesss");
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            if (mSwipeRefreshLayout1.isRefreshing()) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);


        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("WebView1").setTag("WebView1"));
//all the way down to .....
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("WebView30").setTag("WebView30"));        

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);


        final PagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout
                .getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(
                tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        //    int id = item.getItemId();

//        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.WebView1) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

//all the way down to..30

 if (id == R.id.WebView30) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(30);






        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the code for TabPagerAdapter

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    int tabCount;


    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = numberOfTabs;

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
//
                WebViewFragment1 tab1 = new WebViewFragment1();
                return tab1;

   //all the way to tab 29

    webViewFragment30 tab30 = new WebViewFragment30();
return tab30



            default:
                return null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are initializing your `ViewPager`?

Comment: Updated view pager

Answer (score 9):

Use `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` will hold maximum 3 fragments in memory at any time(without changing the default offscreen page limit). The 3 fragments are the current visible fragment, left and right side fragments to the current fragment.

If you want tabs, you could create a custom View which looks like the system Tabs and add it above the ViewPager. Use `PageTransformer` with `ViewPager` to track the `ViewPager` swipe and scroll the custom Tab accordingly. Then listen to the clicks of Tabs and scroll the `ViewPager` based on the Tab pressed.

**Update:**

I totally forgot that we could attach a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` instead of creating custom Tabs.

`tabLayout.setUpWithViewPager(viewpager)` will work.

Thanks to @choman

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but tablayout or viewpager not occupied more memory.

Comment: I am using a view pager with tablayout

Comment: Yes, forgot that we could attach a TabLayout with ViewPager.

Answer (score 5):

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);` This line is causing the issue. This line tells the view pager to keep (6+6+1 = 13) pages in memory which should be costly in your case since each page has 6.5 Mb of contents. You need to change it to `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` to fix the OutOfMemory issue.

Comment: Yes sir I have tried without setting up page limit but it is not what i want. I am in two minds with performance or providing user friendly experience as i dont want the webpage to reload evertime the user swipes from tabs to tabs by removing the page limit.

Comment: If you don't want the webpage to reload everytime then you need to implement caching in WebView. Keeping multiple webviews in memory is not a  good solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting your comment, "I am using only single webview in app but my webpage having 6.5MB size. So it was main reason of app crash".

If your webpage is 6.5MB size, my hunch is that it is because of some large size high quality images. If that is the case, you should consider reducing the size of the images by downscaling/ downsampling the images. Downscaling the images at the server side is much better than doing that in mobile after downloading(waste of bandwidth, CPU, battery).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **android:largeHeap="true"** to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices. On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.

it causes because your application need more space to run.
i think it will help you to solve out current problem.
**--how to use--**

```
<application
        ....
        android:largeHeap="true" >
```

thanks

Comment: I have tried it but its not working for large size image.

Comment: i have remove large size image from my url otherwise i will post here.

Answer (score 2):

WebView is heavy component.

I would recommend to change your application to work with single webview and changing url in it instead of multiple webview usage.

Comment: I am using only single webview in app but my webpage having 6.5MB size. So it was main reason of app crash